# How to find all maximas if x and y values of the function are given as np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, curve-fitting, derivative

I have two numpy arrays x and y, I have plotted a curve with these values. Now I want to find all the values of x where local maxima exists on that curve. How it will be done?

Please give a method to fit the best possible curve with these x and y values and the values of x (or the indices of the value of x in array x) where local maxima exists.

Comment: Can you provide an example data set? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Unless you define what a `best possible curve` is, your question is meaningless.

Comment: @cel : best possible curve means, The curve plotted by taking those x and y values. I want those x where local maximum occurs.

Comment: @Cleb : can u give ur email id so that i can mail u the data set. the data set is huge (2287 x and y values).

Comment: Then just post a subset of your data or a minimal example

Comment: 25.04420302,6.4726
24.9237955,6.3794
24.80454022,6.2407
24.68642074,5.9546
24.5694209,6.02
24.45358465,6.3752
24.3387763,6.4521
24.22504094,6.5293
24.11236361,6.874
24.00072962,7.2593
23.89012454,7.4043
23.78053421,7.6499
23.67194472,8.1933
23.56434244,8.5998
23.45771395,8.9446
23.35204611,9.3696
23.24732598,9.8728
23.14354087,10.2693
23.04067832,10.5884
22.93872607,10.8491
22.83767211,11.0273
22.7375046,11.2046
22.63821194,11.351
22.53978272,11.373
22.44220571,11.4511
22.3454699,11.5783
22.24956446,11.5554
22.15447875,11.5808
22.06020229,11.6865
21.966773,11.7422
21.874084,11.7846
21.78,11.81

Comment: values are in (x,y) ordered pair. like 
x = 25.04420302,24.9237955,24.68642074
y = 6.4726,6.3794,6.2407 etc

Comment: I added a simple example below which should be quite efficient. Please let me know whether it has to be revised; if not, feel free to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=np.array([6,3,5,2,1,4,9,7,8])
y=np.array([2,1,3,5,7,9,8,10,7])

sort_idx = np.argsort(x)
y=y[sort_idx]
x=x[sort_idx]
minm=np.array([],dtype=int)
maxm=np.array([],dtype=int)
length = y.size
i=0

while i < length-1:
    if i < length - 1:
        while i < length-1 and y[i+1] >= y[i]:
            i+=1

        if i != 0 and i < length-1:
            maxm = np.append(maxm,i)

        i+=1

    if i < length - 1:
        while i < length-1 and y[i+1] <= y[i]:
            i+=1

        if i < length-1:
            minm = np.append(minm,i)
        i+=1


print minm,maxm
```

array minm and maxm contain indices of minimas and maximas respectively...

Answer (score 0):

I added code for a simple example below which finds all local minima and all local maxima of an array and stores them in `minVal` and `maxVal`, respectively. Please note: When you apply this to large datasets, make sure to smooth the signals first; otherwise you will end up with tons of extrema.

The data looks as follows; the calculated minima/maxima are at `[2, 5, 7]` and `[1, 3, 6]`, respectively:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X=np.arange(9)
Y=np.array([ 3,  5,  1,  9,  3,  2, 10,  7,  8])
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()
maxVal = argrelextrema(Y, np.greater) #(array([1, 3, 6]),)
minVal = argrelextrema(Y, np.less) #(array([2, 5, 7]),)
```